# How to append response data in freshchat?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using freshchat services for messages,need to send the username, their email, and plan that he selected. I am retreiving data from database using ajax request and append data into freshchat instances but unable to append it correctly.

> Script

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_chat_data',
        type:'get',
        
        success: function(response) {
            let data =  JSON.parse(response); 
            
            console.log(data);
            window.fcWidget.init(data,{
            token: "***************",
            host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com" })
            window.fcWidget.setExternalId(`${data.profile.id}`);
            window.fcWidget.user.setFirstName(`${data.user.username}`);
            window.fcWidget.user.setEmail(`${data.user.email}`);
            window.fcWidget.user.setProperties({
            plan: `${data.package}`,                 // meta property 1
            status: `${data.profile.m_status}`                // meta property 2
            });
        },
    });
  }
      function initialize(i,t){var e;i.getElementById(t)?initFreshChat():((e=i.createElement("script")).id=t,e.async=!0,e.src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js",e.onload=initFreshChat,i.head.appendChild(e))}function initiateCall(){initialize(document,"freshchat-js-sdk")}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",initiateCall,!1):window.attachEvent("load",initiateCall,!1);
```

> Ajax Response:

```
   user: [
        "id" => 41
        "username" => "Jessica John"
        "user_type" => "user"
        "email" => "john@protonmail.com"
      ],
    profile: [
        "m_status" => "Approved"
      ],
   package:
        [
          "Premium"
       ]
```

> Output:

[image]

Comment: Please provide all text, including data, as text, not as pictures of text. See [ask].

Comment: @HereticMonkey Please check again

Comment: Hi, this `${data.profile.id}` should be `${data.user.id}`